# Проверка связи в django

Tags: django

Как проверить *manytomany* связь двух объектов?

```
class CustomUser(User):
   nick=models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, verbose_name=u'Ник')
   birthday=models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=u'День рождения')
   status=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, verbose_name=u'Статус')
   creed=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, verbose_name=u'Кредо')
   friends=models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, default=False)
   moderator=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: print (type(request.user)) выдает <class 'django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject'>, это вряд ли мне что то дает. В других местах атрибуты request.user работают везде как CustomUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if first_object.secondobject_set.filter(pk=second_object.pk).count():
    …
```

Comment: Вот такой views: 
    def another_profile(request, id):

        user1=request.user

        user2=CustomUser.objects.get(id=id)

        if user1.user2__set.filter(pk=user2.pk).count():

            friend=True

выдает ошибку 'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'user2__set'. как исправить?

Comment: Вообще если вы правильно описали модель, то проверка будет выглядеть так:

    if user1.customuser_set.filter(pk=user2.pk).count():

но хотелось бы конечно посмотреть на этого CustomUser…

Comment: Ну а как правильно составить проверку?

Comment: Ясно, а как вы заставили django использовать эту модель вместо django.contrib.auth.models.User ?

Comment: Нашел решение в интернете, там свой auth_backends, где то User подменяется на CustomUser

Comment: ясно, ну если вы уверены в том решении и в контексте действительно ваша модель то долно работать так:

    if user1.customuser_set.filter(pk=user2.pk).count():

Comment: Нет, говорит про отсутствие атрибута customuser_set

Comment: Ну значит в конексте обычный юзер а не кастомный… Можно посмотреть выведя ptint(type(request.user))